# Keeping a receiver alive after the service get killed

Tags: android

I'll start by telling the story first ..

I Have Service mService, Receiver mReceiver, PreferenceFragment with a switch .

Now, This switch will run the service, which will register a Screen.OFF receiver, When the screen get off, the receiver will be called, and it will check if the screen is locked, if yes it will output a log message .

So, Locking means killing the service, the receiver get only called twice and then go off, I've registered the receiver and unrigstered it in the onDestory in mService .

I've added a boolean, And thought about adding a "if" statement in onDestroy, if it's On and getting killed, then run the service when the device get unlocked .

Another thought, It's making the service alive ( which will drain the battery ) .

What i want, to keep listen to Screen.OFF, And i don't want to start use one of them without an advice about using, or maybe i understood it in wrong way ? .

Codes are the basic one, Register / unRegister / class extends Service.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to keep Receiver working - You need something that hosts this receiver.
So yes, You need to keep the service alive.

Comment: Is the "if the option is on, re-enable when unlocked" method is a good practice ? or not a "pro" method .

Comment: Maybe I don't understand You, but how are You going to start service when the device get unlocked? Who or what will listen to device unlocking?